# spring batch StaxEventItemReader release out an exception

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch

when I running a project of spring batch, exception occured!

Exception detail:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.moveCursorToNextFragment(StaxEventItemReader.java:141)
```

fileName is correct!

configuration code:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public StaxEventItemReader xmlFileItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['fileType']}") String fileType,
                                             @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['extractFileName']}") String fileName) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("======================== fileName =========================="+fileName);

    StaxEventItemReader reader = new StaxEventItemReader();

    reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(fileName));
    reader.setFragmentRootElementName("PortData");
    reader.setUnmarshaller(unmarshaller());

    reader.afterPropertiesSet();

    return reader;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I wish I could comment on Padis response, as it put me on track for finding the solution.

I had the same nullPointerException problem with a reader and a writer scoped in @StepScope.
Padis is totally right, when he writes that, when the type of the @Bean is `ItemReader` or `ItemWriter`the `doOpen()` function is not called (It causes the `NullPointerException`)

It happens that, changing the type of my beans from `ItemReader<T>` to `ItemStreamReader<T>` and `ItemWriter<T>` to `ItemStreamWriter<T>` was the solution for me.

Comment: Thank you, I got the same problem and this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Before all check [this thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?85550-Bug-in-StaxEventItemReader) and check if your xml file is composed by a single object element like:

```
<Object>
  <child1>...</child1>
  <child2>...</child2>
  <child3>...</child3>
</Object>
```

because StAX reader implementation works for files like

```
<root>
  <Object>...</Object>
  <Object>...</Object>
<root>
```

If this solve the problem, stop reading!
Else apparently there aren't errors in your configuration.

Assuming latest version (2.2.1.RELEASE)
Error is in this line at `StaxEventItemReader.moveCursorToNextFragment()`

```
while (reader.peek() != null && !reader.peek().isStartElement()) {
```

so, most probably, `reader` is null; or you have unmarshal problems and reader go into trouble.
Is error thrown at first read or after a random number of reads?
Put a breakpoint in check `StaxEventItemReader.doOpen()` or set log level to debug and look if something goes wrong-

Comment: thx a lot my xml file might looks a little complex. <root> <msg>my msg</msg> <datalist> <data> <id>001</id> <name>robin</name> </data </root>

Comment: I think "setFragmentRootElementName" should extract fragments from xml,why it failed

Comment: Why unaccepted? if PortData is the root of xml file you will run into your problem. 
@robinson.L: what do you mean? setFragmentRootElementName is used to move from child to child objects; if you need composition you have to override `StaxEventItemReader.moveCursorToNextFragment()`

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar problem right now. With `@StepScope` set on the reader `open()` method is not called.

`TaskletStep` calls `open()` on `CompositeItemStream` when step is executed. It calls open on every ItemStream. The reader with `@StepScope` does not seem to be set on `CompositeItemStream`.

Make sure that step builder registers your reader in `SimpleStepBuilder.registerAsStreamsAndListeners()`. The problem that I had was that type of my reader bean was `ItemReader` and proxied registered it is not instance of `ItemStream`. Changing the type of my reader bean to `ItemStream` (`StaxEventItemReader`) fixed the problem.