# Spring Batch process multiple files concurrently

Tags: concurrency, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch to process a large XML file (~ 2 millions entities) and update a database. The process is quite time-consuming, so I tried to use **partitioning** to try to speed up the processing.

The approach I'm pursuing is to split the large xml file in smaller files (say each 500 entities) and then use Spring Batch to process each file in parallel.
I'm struggling with the Java configuration to achieve the processing of multiple xml files in parallel. These are the relevant beans of my configuration

```
@Bean
public Partitioner partitioner(){
    MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();

    Resource[] resources;
    try {
        resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources("file:/tmp/test/*.xml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("I/O problems when resolving the input file pattern.",e);
    }
    partitioner.setResources(resources);
    return partitioner;
}

@Bean
public Step partitionStep(){
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("test-partitionStep")
            .partitioner(personStep())
            .partitioner("personStep", partitioner())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step personStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("personStep")
            .<Person, Person>chunk(100)
            .reader(personReader())
            .processor(personProcessor())
            .writer(personWriter)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
    asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(10);
    return asyncTaskExecutor;
}
```

When I execute the job, I get different **XML parsing errors** (every time a different one). If I remove all the xml files **but one** from the folder, then the processing works as expected.

I'm not sure I understand 100% the concept of Spring Batch partitioning, especially the "slave" part.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're getting XML parsing errors, my bet is that you're not splitting the XML files correctly.  Each file must be a complete and valid XML document.  Including the actual error you are receiving as well as how you are splitting the original file would help us help you further.

Comment: Is your reader thread-safe? You may want to try putting it in step scope.

Comment: @DeanClark no, the reader is not thread-safe. Can you please explain "putting in step scope"?

Comment: @MichaelMinella Michael, the files are split correctly. As I mentioned in the original question, if I process each file "alone" everything works. As soon as I use multiple files, than the reader starts spitting out all sort of errors (unclosed tag, etc.). The reader is "StaxEventItemReader" which, according to the documentation, is not thread safe: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/xml/StaxEventItemReader.html

Comment: Correct that the `StaxEventItemReader` is not thread safe, but I was assuming you configured it to be `StepScope` so that you'd have a unique instance per partition.  If that isn't the case, yes, you're going to see the kind of errors you're seeing.

Comment: [Step Scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#step-scope) is briefly described here. It will create one instance per partition/thread and also allows for late-binding of values from the step execution. Having one instance per thread should get around your issues.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the pointers. I got it to work. I stumbled into a nullpointerexception, after adding @StepScope to my StaxReader, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30715287/6564279) answer helped to fix the problem.